# How to share NSHTTPCookieStorage in iOS 8 Extension?

Tags: ios, ios8-extension

I am working on an app that uses NSHTTPCookieStorage to store user data. I can't get to access the cookies inside the extension, as are saved inside Library. Thank you.

Comment: Did you figure how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are not intended to be shared between applications (see [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/)).

Do you know which cookies in particular you are looking for? If you have a way of identifying the ones you want, you could copy them yourself to keychain or a shared CoreData store.

This way both your app and extension will have access to them.

Using NSHTTPCookieStorage is not a preferred way of storing user data.
If you aim for simplicity and don't want CoreData or Keychain you could just use a plist. This also allows you to use NSFileProtectionComplete to provide a layer of security to the data you are storing.